# How can I select an item in a wpf combobox when it is a prefix of a previous item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, wpf-controls

I'll start with my code example.  It's a WPF Application.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="DemoComboBoxProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemoComboBoxProblem"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="60" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Name="CB0" Grid.Column="0" Width="60">
            <ComboBoxItem>CRLF</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>CR</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>LF</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>LFCR</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Name="CB1" Grid.Column="1" Width="60">
            <ComboBoxItem>CRLF</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>AA</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>BB</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>LFCR</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace DemoComboBoxProblem
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CB0.Text = "CR";
            CB1.Text = "AA";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to programatically select the item "CR" in CB0 and the item "AA" in CB1.

When I run this, CB0 displays nothing and (I assume) no item is selected in it.  CB1 correctly displays and has selected "AA".  I think this has something to do with "CR" being a prefix of "CRLF".  I can get it to work if I change the order of the items, but I'm wondering: what is the correct way to make it work with the items in the order given?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do it programatically? You can do it in XAML if you want.

Comment: You can set in XAML SelectedIndex in ComboBox. But the best way will be use MVVM pattern with bindings.

Comment: Have you tried using `CB0.SelectedValue = "CR";`? It could make the difference, although it is unusual why `.Text` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, add SelectedValuePath = "Content" to the combobox properties.

```
<ComboBox Name="CB0" Grid.Column="0" Width="60" SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem>CRLF</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>CR</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>LF</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>LFCR</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

in the code use:

```
CB0.SelectedValue = "CR"; 
CB1.SelectedValue = "AA";
```